# Getting local computer name or IP address from inside of a SQL CLR in RDP Session

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I have a C# (.NET 4.5) SQL CLR (SQL Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2).  Users login via RDP to run an app which in turn calls this CLR.

**I am trying to find out either the local computer name or the local IP address from inside of the CLR.**

I have dumped the whole environment to a log file from the CLR and there is no CLIENTNAME variable set (not surprising, since it is likely the SQL process' environment rather than the user's), so I cannot use that.

I tried importing the Cassia DLL and using it, but the ClientIPAddress of the TerminalServicesManager class is null, so that does not seem to work either.

Is there any way to get the local computer name or IP from a SQL CLR?

Comment: When you say "local", you mean the client side, not the server side, correct? "Local" seems a bit ambiguous of a term here ;). And yes, SQLCLR runs inside of SQL Server's CLR host, hence on the server itself.

Comment: @srutzky Yes, I mean client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using "local" to mean the client's (i.e. the end-user; the one using Remote Desktop to get to the server) IP Address. This is definitely an interesting (and tricky) problem to solve given that the connection to SQL Server is being made from the local machine due to using RDP. And if you shell out of SQL Server's process, either via `xp_cmdshell` or SQLCLR, you are now in a subprocess that originated from a process on the server, not on the client's machine. There is pretty much no connection between the client's machine and SQL Server.

Fortunately, there is a way to get this info IF each user is connecting with their own Login (Windows Login or SQL Server Login) instead of a shared one (a shared Login is more likely to happen when using SQL Server Logins).

If everyone has their own individual Login, then you can do the following:

1. Create a table to hold fields such as:

   - `[Login] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL`
   - `ClientName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL`
   - `CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL
                          CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_CreateDate] DEFAULT (GETDATE())`
2. Create a Logon Script (a **.cmd** script) that will be associated with their profile, at least on that server, if not in their Active Directory Roaming Profile (if you are using AD).
3. The Logon Script will simply call SQLCMD to insert the environment variable `CLIENTNAME` into the table:

   ```
   SQLCMD -Q "INSERT INTO dbo.ClientHostNames (fields) VALUES (ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), N'%CLIENTNAME%');"
   ```

   This works because DOS variables are substituted before the command is executed.
4. In your SQLCLR code, make a connection using the in-process `"Context Connection = true;"` ConnectionString, since this will execute as the Login running the SQLCLR code.
5. Get the hostname using a query similar to:

   ```
   SELECT HostName
   FROM   dbo.ClientHostNames
   WHERE  WindowsLogin = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
   ORDER BY CreateDate DESC;
   ```
6. You can just use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` to get the `HostName` value.

It's not the most direct means, but so far I can't find anything else that will work. And I have tried setting a User environment variable and then trying to grab that in SQLCLR while using Impersonation, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Interesting approach!  I will try to test it today and let you know.

Comment: I tested your solution and it worked great!  One note: I did not have to set the app to use Windows Logins - it worked fine with SQL login as well.  Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @JimBalo Glad it worked. Thanks for letting me know that SQL Server Logins also work :-). I think I said that they wouldn't since my first attempt was for the User environment variable and the thought was going that route would require using Impersonation within the SQLCLR. But when Impersonation didn't switch the registry context, I didn't reevaluate. But I have updated the answer now to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try it .. Hopefully it will `work`

```
    public string GetIPAddress()
    {
        System.Net.IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()); // `Dns.Resolve()` method is deprecated.

        string tempIp = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in ipHostInfo.AddressList)
        {
            tempIp = item.ToString();
            //Make your comparison here
        }
        return tempIp;
    }
```

Comment: Moumit, the O.P. is not looking to get the IP of the machine that SQL Server is running on, but the IP or Hostname/Machine name of the client's computer that is making the Remote Desktop connection _to_ the server that SQL Server is running on.